# Navigate between view controllers without storyboards/xibs

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm developing an application without storyboards/xibs, which is proving to be a challenge. I have a `UICollectionView` (of ads) where users can tap on a cell to navigate to a new view controller to show details for that ad. Below is a gif of the error I'm having.

[image]

As you can see, the `UICollectionView` kind of sticks around after I tap the cell. I have a `adDetailsViewController` property in my `AdsViewController` subclass, and when I tap the cell this code executes:

```
adDetailsViewController.adTitle = adTitles[indexPath.row]
navigationController?.pushViewController(adDetailsViewController, animated: true)
```

Below are the life cycle methods (currently just `viewDidLoad`) of `adDetailsViewController`:

```
class AdDetailsViewController: UIViewController {

    var adTitle: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let label = UILabel(frame: view.bounds)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.center = view.center
        label.text = adTitle

        view.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's the rest of `AdsViewController`:

```
class AdsViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var collectionView: AdsCollectionView = {
       let collectionView = AdsCollectionView(frame: view.frame, collectionViewLayout: TiledFlowLayout())
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(AdCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "AdCell")
        view.addSubview(collectionView)
        return collectionView
    }()

    let adDetailsViewController = AdDetailsViewController()

    let adTitles = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
        collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true

        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}

extension AdsViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return adTitles.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "AdCell", for: indexPath) as! AdCollectionViewCell

        cell.textLabel.text = adTitles[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }
}

extension AdsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        adDetailsViewController.adTitle = adTitles[indexPath.row]
        navigationController?.pushViewController(adDetailsViewController, animated: true)
    }
}

extension AdsViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: (self.view.frame.size.width / 2) - 10, height: self.view.frame.size.height / 4)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 5, bottom: 0, right: 5)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is happening because you are animating the change of the `ViewControllers`. If you set the `animated:` parameter to `false` then the change will be instant, if this is what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want the normal transition to happen when tapping the cells, i.e the new view controller slides on top of it. I don't want it to happen instantly.

Comment: Please, add UIViewController's lifecycle methods of adDetailsViewController

Comment: Just added it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to share more of your code. Are there any special settings f.e.? Like a transparent background? Anything you do in viewDidLoad? Did you overwrite viewWillAppear, viewDidAppear, etc. and did not call the subclass functions (like super.viewWillAppear(animated))? That's a very common mistake...

Comment: I just added code for `AdsViewController` and `AdDetailsViewController`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. It seems that if I set the `backgroundColor` of `AdDetailsViewController` to `UIColor.white`, then it transitions as expected.